# Latest version Libreoffice Headless CentOS

Tags: centos, updates, libreoffice

I am somewhat new to using Linux so my apologies if this seems like a simple question. The problem I am facing right now is an outdated version of Libreoffice.  The server is running CentOS 6 Libreoffice headless version 3.4.  It is my understanding that Libreoffice has reached 4.1.  I need a later version because 3.4 is lacking some functionality that I need.  When I try to update using YUM it says I have the latest version.

I have seen later versions of the headless version of Libreoffice for Fedora but I'm guessing I cannot use these.  Is it possible for me to use later versions from other distros other than CentOS?  Or am I stuck using ver 3.4 for now?

Comment: Did you want to post what repositories you are using along with this question?

Comment: I am using 1h, epel, extras, percona and updates.